# Some colours on my MacBook Air are overly saturated

Tags: macos, display, color

Some colors of my (original) MacBook Air (2015) integrated display are overly saturated when playing a video in full screen. This occurs on very specific conditions (or maybe the issue is simply exacerbated):

- A video is playing (Youtube, Netflix, etc.) in full screen
- Controls are hidden (play/pause, etc.) and the video is playing
- Night shift is turned on

This issue manifests itself by the presence of flat areas of colour that are overly saturated compared to what it should look like. The colour profile in the Display preferences is set to "Colour LCD" (the default). I tried other profiles and the issue seems to only occur with the default one.

I was unable to capture a visual representation of the issue by recording the screen of taking a screenshot with the Screenshot app as it seems to remove the visual artefacts. Here are few captures made with an external camera (the visual artefacts are stronger in reality).

First sample (without/with issue):
[image: first image without issue]
[image: first image with issue]

One artefact can be seen on the top right corner as a very deep purple flat area.

Second sample (without/with issue):
[image: second image without issue]
[image: second image with issue]

### In this second sample the artefact manifests as a bright yellow disk at the center of the lamp.

I wasn't able to find other posts mentioning a similar problem. I have this issue since Night Shift exists as far as I remember and no update nor reboot ever removed it. I'm considering trying the solution of this [SO question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3640990), **is it safe to restaure de Display preferences in this way?**. **Is there anything else I can try?**.

Comment: did you try the ColorSync utility in Apple utility folder

Comment: @Ruskes yes, I tried a Verify and a Repair procedure without result. In the Devices tab it says that my current display profile is the factory one, which sounds normal.

Comment: do you have another screen to test.Also is your night shit off

Comment: I don't have another screen to test unfortunately. The issue occurs when Night Shift is on as said in the post.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that, so did you try to change the color temperature in night shift

Comment: you could also use HDMI cable to your TV, just trying to isolate is it the driver or your LCD screen

Comment: Changing the temperature of Night Shift does not changes the problem unfortunately. Ok I’ll try your last suggestion as soon as I can.